# Using date picker control how to enable particular days

Tags: asp.net

Using date picker control I want to enable Saturday only and remaining dates should be disabled.

Comment: Is this with `jQuery`, `JavaScript`, the `ASP.NET` control?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [`DateTimePicker.MinDate Property`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.mindate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property of Datetime Picker control probably to have the minimum date and time that can be selected in the control. Again, you will have to set it to a specific date and not like all Saturdays.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the standard calendar ASP.NET control.
You can implement the DayRender event and set `e.Day.IsSelectable = false;` on all days except saturday.

`protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Day.Date.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            {
                e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
                e.Cell.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.BlueViolet;
            }
        }`